# Iteration CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to read my from my csv file, iterate over it to find certain strings, then add another row and column with new strings if said string is found. 
For example i am trying to iterate over the file to find the string flour(but datatype says its object, of string value i assume), if flour is found in that column i can append a new row called Allergen1 and call it Gluten. Plan is to do the same thing for a few more allergens. Like Allergen2 would be Eggs, etc. Below is what i have so far.

CSV looks like this. Its too big for me to type here but here is a link to the raw csv file. [enter link description here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cweber/cookbook/master/recipes.csv).

This section lets me add a new row called Allergen1 and insert 'flour' in the column. Which works fine on it own when used. The testing.csv is just a file i have made locally so i can test results.

```
input_file = pd.read_csv('recipes.csv')
input_file['Allergen2'] = 'flour'
input_file.to_csv('testing.csv', index=False)
```

This is what i have so far, just a basic iteration. I have tried different variations of pandas and python ways to read the csv file.

```
input_file = csv.DictReader(open('recipes.csv'))
for row in input_file:
if ('flour') in row.values():
    input_file['Allergen100'] = 'Gluten'
    input_file.to_csv('testing.csv', index = False)
```

My problem is that the iteration works just fine and it prints every row from my csv. I just cant figure out how to use my add new row and column segment from above in my if statement. Error i get is

> TypeError: 'DictReader' object does not support item assignment

Does anyone what it means and how i can solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The csv module is a very basic module and doesn't not include any of the fancy aspects of pandas. In particular, the csv.DictReader doesn't actually write anything to memory, hence there is no array to update (unlike pandas); instead csv.DictReader simply returns each line of the csv file, one at a time. If you don't save those lines to a new variable, then they are thrown away. The csv module would be helpful in situtations where want to process a 100 GB csv file, but only have 10 GB of RAM. The csv module allows you to go line by line and read the csv file and perform actions based on what you have read. Pandas on the other hand would attempt to open the entire csv file into memory, which allows you to update the memory on the fly before rewriting a new csv file.

If you wrap csv.DictReader in a list() you will iterator through all the lines and read the whole file into memory.

```
#Read
f = open('recipes.csv')
input_file = list(csv.DictReader(f))
for row in input_file:
    if 'flour' in row.values():
        row['Allergen100'] = 'Gluten'
f.close()

#Write
f = open('testing.csv','w')
output_file = csv.DictWriter(f,input_file[0].keys())
output_file.writeheader()
output_file.writerows(input_file)
f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did read something about this earlier but didn't know about it being the case now. Learned something new and the result worked great.